# Why does a Select List with ng-options make the user think they've chosen a blank value?

Tags: angularjs

I have a Select List that gets its values from an array.

```
ng-options="obj.Value as obj.Text for obj in SelectListOptions track by obj.Value"
```

This seems to work fine and shows the options to the user. But when the user selects one of those values the Select box just has a blank, as though they've chosen a blank value. The property is updated in the model just fine, but it gives the user an impression they've chosen a blank value.

Replicated it in [this Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mikerouse/wh8gfcvf/).

Always seems to have this as the first item and this is always the selected option:

```
<option value="?" selected="selected"></option>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because angular uses the `track by` functionality to decide which item is selected, which seems to break when you use `select as` and `track by` simultaneously.

Please refer to the angular [documentation for select](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select) in the section `select as with trackexpr`

To fix this for your case, simply remove the `track by obj.Value` part of your `ng-options` expression and it's all resolved. The only "downside" to this is that angular applies temporary tracking IDs to your select items, but usually that isn't an issue.

Comment: Thanks for this, very helpful. Unfortunately I need the tracking as I want to save the selected value to my database. I was hoping to avoid mapping the temporary value Angular applies to the values my database wants.

Comment: You could work around this by not using `ngOptions` to fill your select item, but create the set of `<option>` items yourself via `ngRepeat`. Then you have more influence on the details.